# After changing to SSL index.php post fix is expected before server requests

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, http, https

I installed Mautic in an AWS server and it was working fine on the port 80. But when change to the following site configuration in `mautic.conf` (placed in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mautic.conf) to use `SSL`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@xxxx.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mautic/
        ServerName xxxx.com
        ServerAlias xxxx.com
        DirectoryIndex index.php/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mautic-error_log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mautic-access_log common


        <Directory /var/www/html/mautic/>
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
                RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@xxxx.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mautic/
        ServerName xxxx.com
        ServerAlias xxxx.com
        DirectoryIndex index.php/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mautic-error_log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mautic-access_log common
        SSLEngine On

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

        <Directory /var/www/html/mautic/>
                SSLRequireSSL On
                SSLVerifyClient optional
                SSLVerifyDepth 1
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +StrictRequire
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

my .htaccess file is as belows,

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
#DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Set Authorization header for OAuth1a for when php is running under fcgi
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^(?!/(index\.php|index_dev\.php|app|addons|plugins|media|upgrade))(/(.*))$ /index.php$2
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
~                                                                                                                                                                                                             
~                                                                                                                                                                                                             
~                                                                                                                                                                                                             
~                                                                                                                                                                                                             
~
```

But now when I go to the `https://xxxx` or `http://xxxx` it redirects to `https://xxxx/s/dashboard` (which is a 404 error).

But the actual working page is available in the, `https://xxxx/index.php/s/dashboard`.

I am not sure from there does this index.php is coming from (This was there and getting redirected fine when I was using port 80).

Is there any work around to always add `/index.php/` to all the server requests.

And I am curious to know what is the underling issue here.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am having the same problem

Comment: Yes I remember we fixed this. But I do not have proper documentation around that. If I find this I will put this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same behavior on a very different installation.

It's a misconfiguration/incompatibility between the SSL redirect and mautic's provided .htaccess file.

Check the rewrite rules to see if anything is being re-configured when it shouldn't. If I'm not wrong the Apache conf would be run first and later the .htaccess would apply.